# Modifying the object of TreeSet in Java

Tags: java, class

If I have a class as follows

```
 class tree implements Comparable

{
    int line_no;
    line_segment line[];

    public int compareTo(Object obj)
    {
        tree t = (tree)obj;
        if(this.line[line_no]< t.line[line_no])
               return 1;
            else if(this.line[line_no]==t.line[line_no])
               return 0;
            else 
               return -1;

    }
```

If I create a TreeSet of the following class in which each object's array variable "**line**" points to the same object defined in the main method. How can I modify the variable array named "**line**" so that the results can be seen in the treeSet insertion for the new elements and the elements already present in the treeset remains unchanged.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I've read your question three times and have no idea what you're asking. Can you re-phrase, please?

Comment: Your code doesn't match your description. You probably mean   `(line[this.line_no] < line[t.line_no])`. Also you should add the equals case (ie `return 0;`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Important EDIT, see bottom of answer

Currently, you are probably creating your `tree` objects like this:

```
line_segment line[] = new line_segment[n];
for (int i=0; i<lines; i++)
{
    tree t = new tree();
    t.line_no = i;
    t.line_segment = line;
    treeSet.add(t);
}
```

You have to create a **new** array for each `tree` that you are creating:

```
for (int i=0; i<lines; i++)
{
    tree t = new tree();
    t.line_no = i;

    // Create new array for each element
    line_segment line[] = new line_segment[n];

    t.line_segment = line;
    treeSet.add(t);
}
```

Also note that you should **not** modify the *elements* of this array after the `tree` has been inserted into the TreeSet. Otherwise, the behavior of the TreeSet will be unspecified.

---

EDIT: Based on the code, one has to consider the possibility that you *want* the arrays to be equal, and that each element should only refer to one particular line of the array. In this case, you do *not* have to create a new array for each element. But when you change the contents of the array, then the TreeSet will become inconsistent. In this case, a simple (very pragmatic) workaround could be to remove the element, perform the modification of the array, and then re-insert the element. But I assume that there is a more elegant solution for whatever you want to achieve.

Comment: What if this line array is common to all the lines which I create and then try to modify it?

Comment: @user3327899 Then you will modify the common array and they will all see that change.

Comment: All other `tree` elements will see the same modification, **but the TreeSet will become inconsistent**. You may **not** modify an object after it has been inserted into a TreeSet or HashSet. (More precisely: You may not modify it in a way that affects the behavior of `compareTo`, `hashCode` or `equals`)

Comment: Do the TreeSet handle this form of editing of elements so that it again readjusts its elements ?

Comment: @user3327899 It may turn out that your question really was not clear enough. When each element should only refer to one *entry* of the array, then you do not have to create a new array for each element. I added an EDIT to the answer, but you should probably describe what you *actually* want to achieve.